# Why does my empty folder have 3.46 GB?

Tags: windows

So I've been cleaning up my desktop for the last few minutes, and I tried to delete this empty folder, but it has some 3.46GB of data in it!

Any ideas of why this is happening? I restarted my computer, thinking it was just some kind of fluke, but it is still happening.

[image: screen shot of the problem]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: According to the lower left of your image, you should ask Cortana (because you can ask her anything). You cannot, however, ask Stack Overflow anything (err, not everything, but other items that fit within anything and are programming related are fine).

Comment: Given the icons I see, you're not a noob, so it's only for sureness' sake I ask - any hidden files in that directory?

Comment: @mah You can **ask** Cortana anything. It doesn't promise that you'll get an answer... Also, in Sweden, you can't ask her at all...

Comment: Please do not cross post in the future, ask your question on one site only.

Answer (score 3):

More than likely, the directory contains hidden or system files and your settings by default will **not** show them.

Modify your control panel>folder options>view to display all files.

Answer (score 1):

The folder is not empty,It contain 8714 files and 265 folders in it
They are hidden

Follow these steps to display hidden files and folders.

```
Open Folder Options by clicking the Start button , clicking Control Panel, clicking Appearance and Personalization, and then clicking Folder Options.
Click the View tab.
Under Advanced settings, click Show hidden files and folders, and then click OK.
```